# fancybox compatibility with Slider pro

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

I`m incurring in a compatibility problem between fancybox and slider pro, the plug in I use to visualize videos on my website.

There is this error in teh java code from fancybox:

```
89 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).fancyboxforwp is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):89)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

which occurs in several pages on my wordpress and when fancybox is on it prevents my slider pro plug in to display and work.

Is there a chance this error could be fixed in fancybox?

Best, 
angy

Comment: You have provided the errors but not the code. I might suspect that this has something to do with an incompatibility with your jQuery version, as v 1.2.4 is over 10 years old. Both FancyBox and Slider Pro probably use a more updated version of jQuery, but that is unclear from the information you provided.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I have to confess I don`t understand much of coding...

Comment: I have my fancyboxm plug in active on my website, for example on this page http://www.angypop.com/?portfolio=desplicable-me-2

Comment: I had to deativate it to have the slider pro plug in show up otherwise it doens t

Comment: from where do I upgrade jQuery exactly? is it another plug in?

Comment: That fancybox plugin version if for 2012 and it looks like it is part of your site's theme. The script is loaded from `/themes/clean/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?ver=2012-08-20`. Slider Pro includes 4 jquery extensions for version 3.1. You could try a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/version-control-for-jquery/ to allow multiple versions of jquery to be used.

Comment: ok, thanks, I`ll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message -

```
jQuery(...).fancyboxforwp is not a function
```

So, something is trying to do something like `$('.some-selector').fancyboxforwp()`, but `$.fn.fancyboxforwp` method does not exist and the result is this error message.

Basically, your issue **IS NOT related to fancybox** at all. I do not know what `fancyboxforwp` is, maybe it is created by the authors of your current theme or some plugin, you should check it out by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In `/wp-content/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/fancybox.php`

Look for:

```
wp_register_script( 'fancybox', FBFW_URL . 'assets/js/jquery.fancybox.js', $jquery, '1.3.4', $footer );
```

Replace `1.3.4` with the right version where `'assets/js/jquery.fancybox.js'` is defined